# Pre-render sticky states

Tags: angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am trying to build a tabbed application using Sticky States from UI-Router extras.

The contents of my tabs contain some directives that "register" themselves to a service. I would like to have, on initialization, a full registration so that the service knows all those directives. That means rendering the states in the background, without displaying them, as if the user manually clicked on all the tabs before starting to use the application.

Is there any way I can do this ? Thank you.